# what is wrong with this code in jquery 22

Tags: jquery

can you see what is wrong with this code ? I have a form with 2  input text boxes and 2 submit buttons, when the user clicks the second button ,

it should list all the months starting with letter "J", but for some reason it wont run

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>submit demo</title>
<style>
p {
margin: 0;
color: blue;
}
div,p {
margin-left: 10px;
}
span {
color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Type 'correct' to validate.</p>
<form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
<div>
<input type="text"  >
<input type="text" id ='months' >


<input type="submit"  >

<input type="submit"  id ="other" >
</div>
</form>
<span></span>
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) {
$( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
return;
}
$( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
event.preventDefault();
});


    $(document). ready(function() {


      $( "#other" ).click(function() {


        var months = [  'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
                        'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                        'November', 'December'];
        months = $.grep(months, function(value, i) {
            return ( value.indexOf('J') == 0 );
        });
        $(' #months').html( '<li>' + months.join('</li><li>') + '</li>' );
    });
})



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is some code outside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `months` is an input element not a div/span to use `html()`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G457g/2/

Comment: Woah, is jQuery on version number 22 already? I must have been living under a rock for a century or two then.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>submit demo</title>
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0;
            color: blue;
        }
        div,p {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        span {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Type 'correct' to validate.</p>
    <form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
        <div>
            <input type="text"  >
            <input type="text" id ='months' >

            <input type="submit"  >
            <input type="submit"  id ="other" >
        </div>
    </form>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="m"></ul>
    <script>
        $(document). ready(function() {
            $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) {
                    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
                    return;
                }
                $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
            });

            $( "#other" ).click(function() {

                var months = [  'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
                    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                    'November', 'December'];
                $(months).each(function() {
                    if(this.indexOf('J') === 0)
                        $("#m").html($("#m").html()+"<li>"+this+"</li>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

You should use **event.preventDefault()** at first line of click event and jQuery function **each()** for table iteration.